# Read() is returning without reading

Tags: c, system-calls

I did a project for college where I had to implement a function that:

> Repeated calls (e.g., using a loop) to `get_next_line()` should let you read the text file pointed to by the file descriptor, one line at a time.
> Returns the line that was read. If there is nothing else to read or if an error occurred, it returns `NULL`.
> The returned line includes the terminating `\n` character, except if the end of file was reached and does not end with a `\n` character.

However now that I am doing another project I had to implement this function to read a file and noticed that it crashes my program with SIGABRT whenever finish reading a file close it and then run it on the same file descriptor again.

(run `get_next_line()` several times until end of file; close file; open it again on same fd; run `get_next_line()`).

However for the life of me I can't figure out what is causing this. I suspect some weird behaviour of `read()` but I am not sure.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 42
#define NUM_OF_FD 255

size_t  ft_strlen(const char *s)
{
    size_t  i;

    if (!s)
        return (0);
    i = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    return (i);
}

char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    char    chr;

    chr = (char)c;
    if(!s)
        return (NULL);
    while (*s && *s != chr)
        s++;
    if (*s == chr)
        return ((char *)s);
    else
        return (NULL);
}

char    *strldup(char *s1, int start, int end)
{
    char    *ptr;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    ptr = malloc(end - start + 1);
    if (!ptr)
        return (NULL);
    while (start < end)
        ptr[i++] = s1[start++];
    ptr[i] = 0;
    return (ptr);
}

/*
    Allocates (with malloc) and returns a new string,
    result of the concatenation of s1 and s2
    S1 is freed
*/
char    *ft_strjoinfree(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int     i;
    char    *str;
    char    *hld;
    size_t  size;

    if (!s1 && !s2)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    size = (ft_strlen(s1) + ft_strlen(s2) + 1);
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    if (!str)
        return (NULL);
    hld = s1;
    if (s1)
        while (*s1)
            str[i++] = *s1++;
    if (s2)
        while (*s2)
            str[i++] = *s2++;
    str[i] = '\0';
    if (hld)
        free(hld);
    return (str);
}

char    *returner(char **backup, int fd)
{
    int     index;
    char    *line;
    char    *temp;

    index = ft_strchr(backup[fd], '\n') - backup[fd] + 1;
    line = strldup(backup[fd], 0, index);
    temp = strldup(backup[fd], index, ft_strlen(backup[fd]));
    free(backup[fd]);
    backup[fd] = temp;
    return (line);
}

char    *cycle(char **backup, int fd, char *buf)
{
    int size;

    size = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
    buf[size] = '\0';
    while (size > 0)
    {
        backup[fd] = ft_strjoinfree(backup[fd], buf);
        if (ft_strchr(backup[fd], '\n') != NULL)
            return (returner(backup, fd));
        size = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
        buf[size] = '\0';
    }
    return (NULL);
}

char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    char        buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    static char *backup[NUM_OF_FD];
    char        *line;

    if (fd < 0 || fd > NUM_OF_FD)
        return (NULL);
    line = NULL;
    if (ft_strchr(backup[fd], '\n') == NULL)
    {
        line = cycle(backup, fd, buf);
        if (line != NULL)
            return (line);
    }
    else
        return (returner(backup, fd));
    if (backup[fd] != NULL && *backup[fd] != '\0')
    {
        line = backup[fd];
        backup[fd] = NULL;
        return (line);
    }
    free(line);
    free(backup[fd]);
    return (NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     fd;
    char    *line;  

    //open file
    if (argc != 2)
        exit(1);
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        exit(2);

    //check file and get sizes
    line = get_next_line(fd);
    while (line != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", line);
        free(line);
        line = NULL;
        line = get_next_line(fd);
    }
    close(fd);

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        exit(2);
    //Generates SIGABRT
    line = get_next_line(fd);
    while (line != NULL)
        {
        printf("%s", line);
        free(line);
        line = NULL;
        line = get_next_line(fd);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

File:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0 10 10  0  0 10 10  0  0  0 10 10 10 10 10  0  0  0
0  0 10 10  0  0 10 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10 10  0  0
0  0 10 10  0  0 10 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10 10  0  0
0  0 10 10 10 10 10 10  0  0  0  0 10 10 10 10  0  0  0
0  0  0 10 10 10 10 10  0  0  0 10 10  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0 10 10  0  0  0 10 10  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0 10 10  0  0  0 10 10 10 10 10 10  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I get `SIGABRT`

I know that the `SIGABRT` is coming from the `free()` in `ft_strjoinfree` but for that to happen read must return a value but read nothing.

Note that the code is formatted that way as it is a college requirement no more than 25 lines per function.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you're right, fixed it

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry should have removed them as they don't influence `get_next_line` but i added them just the same.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I corrected it. this edit results in the same error

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It actually reproduces the problem quit and t-data are not relevant as I had stated.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I took them off and the problem still happens. They weren't relevant and I made a mistake when I copy pasted

Comment: That looks a lot better now. Since it appears that you have now provided a [mre], I have removed my comments in which I was asking for one.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I added my version of the strlen functions meanwhile (after your last comment) but now it DOES reproduce the error

Comment: SIGABRT in `free` usually means a buffer overrun or other data corruption in *some other part* of the program, not necessarily anything to do with the `free` call that crashed.

Comment: You should check the return value from `read` before assuming that `buf[size] = '\0';` makes sense.  If `read` should fail, it would return -1, which would be bad for your code.

Comment: @NateEldredge that's so weird, is the fd the same in both `open()`s?
I traced it to the `read()` where it returns 42 but it doesn't put anything in the `buf`

Comment: What does look wrong to me is that when `get_next_line` reaches end of file, it will free `backup[fd]`.  When you open the file again, you may very well get the same fd.  So the next call to `get_next_line` attempts to call `ft_strchr` on that same `backup[fd]` pointer, which points to memory that has been freed.  Not good.

Comment: "it returns 42 but it doesn't put anything in the buf":  I bet that is not what is actually happening.  What specific tests/observations did you make that led you to that conclusion?  You may be misinterpreting them.

Comment: "is the fd the same in both open()s?"  It certainly could be.  `open` may return any fd that is not already open, including one that was previously opened but then closed.  So most likely in this program both `open`s will return the same value, though you should not rely on that always happening.

Comment: @NateEldredge If i comment out that free it does definitely work! however I'm unsure if that leaves my program vulnerable to memory leaks

Comment: I think that instead, after you `free(backup[fd])`, you should also do `backup[fd] = NULL`.  Then, if I understand the code correctly, the next call to `get_next_line` will reinitialize it, as if it were the first time it was being used.

Comment: @NateEldredge I want to kiss you!!! Fixed it! It caused me so much frustration! Can you write an answer so I can mark it as "answered"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    char        buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    static char *backup[NUM_OF_FD];
    char        *line;
    //...
    free(line);
    free(backup[fd]);
    return (NULL);
}
```

When you have reached end-of-file the first time through, you do `free(backup[fd])`.  Now `backup[fd]` contains a (non-null) pointer to unusable memory.  When you reopen the file, it is likely that the same fd is used, and so you continue to use the same `backup[fd]` pointer, accessing freed memory and causing the crash.

It looks like your code is set up to handle a NULL pointer in `backup[fd]` and allocate memory accordingly, since that's what will happen on the first call.   So I think that after freeing `backup[fd]`, you should set it to `NULL`; then the next time through, you will really be starting fresh, and your code will know that fresh memory needs to be allocated.